# Listing files in GCS with apache beam low throughput

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm trying run an apache beam pipeline on Dataflow. The pipeline is supposed to list all files from a location in a bucket and then download all the files. I start by listing and filtering all the files in a bucket and then expanding the files to download them in a ParDo. However the self.list_files seems to have a weird throughput which slows down after a while.

My pipeline code:

```
            pipeline
            | "Get list of zones"                                       >> beam.create(keys)
            | "Get snapshots filenames"                                 >> beam.FlatMap(self.list_files)
            | "Load snapshots"                                          >> beam.ParDo(LoadFiles())
```

The code for listing all the files:

```
    def list_files(
        self, element: Key
    ) -> list[tuple[Key, str]]]:
        blob_names_with_size = beam.io.gcsio.GcsIO().list_files(
            f"{SNAPSHOTS_BASE_URI}/{element}/",
            with_metadata=False,
        )
        blob_names = [blob_name[0] for blob_name in blob_names_with_size]
        input_files_refs = filter_files(blob_names)
        return [
            (element, input_files_ref)
            for input_files_ref in input_files_refs
        ]
```

When I look at the throughput, it seems to scale at first but after a while it starts yielding only a few elements at a time which then slows down all subsequent steps of the pipeline due to the low throughput of this step. Any ideas why this might be and how to improve this ?
[image: Low output of the list file step]

Comment: You are starting a batch pipeline with a certain amount of `keys`. So I am guessing once your pipeline has processed all keys, it is done and won't repeat the `LoadFiles` DoFn.

Comment: Is there any reason you code list_files by yourself without using MatchFiles https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/file-processing/